# How do you set up a combobox in Silverlight to allow clicking through items?

Tags: silverlight, combobox

I have several databound comboboxes in my application and I notice that when i open the combobox to click on an item it doesn't select the item unless i click to the right of the text.  I'm assuming there is some way to include the text area as part of the item in terms of making a selection.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using :

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding time}"/>
```

It worked fine after I switched it to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding time}"/>
```

Now no matter where I click it still selects.

Hope this helps the next guy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip, 
I figured out how to get around it aswell, but like you I thought the default setup would work like this so I searched for a simple answer.
I was wrong you would have to handle the click and pass it back manually

cheers
b